# ruby-xslt, Centos and undefined symbol xsltLibxmlVersion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, centos

I have a rails application using the following environment:

CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Rails 3.0.9
Rubygems 1.6.2
Ruby 1.9.2
Passenger
Apache2

The Development environment differs and is: Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.8.7 which works like a charm. I can't change the production environment.

I use ruby-xslt, gem version 0.9.8, the problem is when I access the application I get an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-xslt-0.9.8/lib/xml/xslt_lib.so: undefined symbol: xsltLibxmlVersion - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-xslt-0.9.8/lib/xml/xslt_lib.so
```

The only solution I can find about this is:

http://amitsolanki.com/2010/04/undefined-symbol-xsltlibxmlversion-ruby-xslt-and-centos/

Which does not work for me.

I am stumped and would like to hear your opinions on what to do:

My ideas are as follows:

1) Don't use ruby-xslt - However this is the only ruby based xslt lib I could get to compile in development, which is why I used it. (but am open to suggestions).

2) Hack the ruby-xslt lib to remove the reference to the symbol, recompile and install. (tried but the error still appears so I may not be doing it right, I run "ruby setup.rb" for the gem again after the change but this is pure guesswork.)

3) Change the Ruby Environment to 1.8.7 as in development - don't think this will work as the problem is between the gem ruby-xslt and a linux library libxslt2.so and not the ruby env. (so actually not going to do this)

4) Add the symbol to the libxslt2.so lib, rebuild and install (but not worked with C language for 15 Years)

Any thoughts on this?

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using option number 1 and managed to get an older version of xslt-ruby installed (1.0.1), this involved installing a few libs as well.